# PostgreSQL Springboot Database Performance Issue

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

We have a simple application in Java using SpringBoot with a backend to PostgreSQL. It is a booking application. So during their peak, they have 50000 people accessing the site at the same time. We only have a single database. Our biggest challenge is that the database is only capable of handling 5000 connections max, based on our research and some trial and error.

How do we optimize PostgreSQL (we are planning to migrate to AWS Aurora for PostgreSQL) in order to handle the spike in traffic during that busy day?

Right now when we load test the site, it becomes unresponsive after 5000 connections. If we increase the value too much, we find that the database does not accept any connection whatsoever at all.

Any help or advice would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Advice: connection pooling.

Comment: What does "at the same time" mean?  Having 50000 logged in at any given point, but each one only sending one request per hour is very different than 50000 requests per second, or per millisecond.

Comment: The question is pretty broad- maybe too much so for an answer. It's really going to depend on your setup and what your application does. Yes, connection pooling is important, but you get that out of box and I would be baffled if you didn't already have it. My first thought would be Open Session in View might be turned on which can be greedy when it comes to borrowing connections from the pool. But to give any answer with confidence, you'll probably need to observe how your connections are being used and ask specific questions about how to reduce the time those connections are borrowed.

Comment: And a word of caution- if you go down the route of disabling Open Session in View, make sure you _thoroughly_ understand what it does, and what needs to be changed before you disable the flag.

Comment: Very broad question. First you need a connection pool, you always do, and second you have to optimize every single query for maximum performance. We handle 5 million unique customers daily on a single database over 20 active database connections. Average database response time is just below 2 milliseconds, that's why we only have 20 active connections. The rest is idle. Queries that would take seconds, would be impossible with just 20 connections.

Comment: We have a very unique scenario, it's a booking site, and every year, on one day of that year, everyone comes to that site trying to book whatever is available. This application allows booking without logging in the user first, so we have to perform database checks and block tickets for anonymous users. We are using Spring Boot, which has a built-in connection pool and session pooling etc. The problem is even when we scale the application using JMeter to load test it, a single database can only handle 10000 users max concurrently. Our test scenario is sending 1000 requests for every 10000 users